# SharePoint save content in session

Tags: session

By default SharePoint will disable session, if we have to use session in web parts, then how should we do so?  If I don't use session, then is there any alternative solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some considerations:

- You could enable the session. There are several blogs or forum posts about that (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237989/enabling-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010).
  But enabling/using the session may have an impact on the performance, especially if you have several front end servers.
- Maybe try to use the ViewState/Cookies instead of the session state.